# How do I edit a border of a shape to be any kind of curve or angle?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to edit a shape on my website using HTML and CSS, so the top border of the shape is a curvy line.[image: Here's an example of what I'd like it to look like]

I attempted using pseudo elements, but I found that I could only use them to make straight lines. Although I am able to put use shapes for the curve, such as circles, it does not give me the ability to customize the lines as I wish them to be, as I demonstrated in the image above

Comment: For such a strange shapes you should consider creating an svg element with vector shapes and place it where you want - I assume you want it as a divider element between sections.

Comment: https://redstapler.co/curved-custom-shape-div-css-svg/

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like this:

Try this:

HTML

```
<div class="class">
   Your text
</div>
```

CSS

```
.class{
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #27b6b9 0%, #0f4061 100%);
}

.class {
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:24px;
  padding-top:25px;
  padding-bottom:25px;
}

.class::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 10px;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-image:
   radial-gradient(circle at 10px -5px, transparent 12px, #fff 13px);
}
.class::after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 15px;
  background-size: 40px 20px;
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(circle at 10px 15px, #fff 12px, transparent 13px);
}
```